# How to merge two databases, both with primary keys

Tags: mysql

I have two databases, both with the same tables, but the data is out of sync.

I need to add data from database A to database B, but not overwrite any data in B that exists in A, instead add it with a new ID.

E.G

Table users in B has a row with ID (auto increment, primary) 5, for a guy called Bob. Table users in A has a record for a guy called Dave in row ID 5.

I'd like Dave to be added to B.users but with a new ID.

I have looked at using Navicats Data Sync, but there are no advanced options to allow this, only to stop it overwriting (updating) or removing the record.

What are my options here? Is it a manual job?

Answer (score 1):

I assume there is a `UNIQUE` index on the column with "Dave" and "Bob"?  Without that, how do you know what is "new"?

Let's call the column `name` (distinct from `id`).

Does some other table depend on Dave=5?  If so, the following will not suffice, and the solution is much messier.

Are there *changes* to the columns?  Or is it only "new" rows to be copied from A to B?

```
INSERT INTO B.user
    SELECT ...  -- excluding `id`
        FROM A.user
        LEFT JOIN B.user  USING(email)
        WHERE B.id IS NULL;     -- Not currently in B
```

To handle changes, look at `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, again with a `JOIN`, but this time `IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: There is an email column which would be unique. Also, there could be changes. I think I'm just going to sync the data regardless, as there isn't much new data to lose that can't be re added via the application.